Assessing the quality of cycle paths with LIDAR data
I'm trying to use the roughness function in QGIS, The problem is with Roughness technique because using compute_edge the function will interpolate the missing neighboring pixels therefore estimating their height. But if we do not compute edge the function will only take the cells which have 9 neighboring pixels and therefore with the cycle paths not very wide this is complicated. Is it possible to mix both by doing the roughness with only the avalaible pixels without interpolating?
